# How can I extract only the date from a timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe just like that:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': ['2017-06-04 07:59:42', '2017-06-04 07:59:42',
                  '2017-06-04 07:59:42', '2017-06-04 07:59:42',
                  '2017-06-04 07:59:42'],
    'municipality_id': [9, 8, 4, 0, 7],
    'usage': [454, 556, 1090, 204, 718],
    'total_capacity': [1332, 2947, 3893, 2813, 2019]
})
```

| timestamp | municipality_id | usage | total_capacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-06-04 07:59:42 | 9 | 454 | 1332 |
| 2017-06-04 07:59:42 | 8 | 556 | 2947 |
| 2017-06-04 07:59:42 | 4 | 1090 | 3893 |
| 2017-06-04 07:59:42 | 0 | 204 | 2813 |
| 2017-06-04 07:59:42 | 7 | 718 | 2019 |

So how can I get the first ten characters of every row of first column like:

```
0    2017-06-04
1    2017-06-04
2    2017-06-04
3    2017-06-04
4    2017-06-04
```

Comment: Do you mean get the first 10 characters from the timestamp column? It also seems like this could be "how can I extract only the date from a timestamp?"

Comment: Yes you are right thanks.

Comment: What is the type of that column?  Is it an actual datetime object, or is it a string?

Comment: Type of column is string.

Comment: post your questions as original dataset (csv, text, etc.) not as image.

Comment: https://pi.works/3w8IJbV

Comment: Downvoting because post contains textual info as images. If this is addressed, I'll be happy to withdraw downvote.

Comment: I dont know if it is true but i tried to fix it.

Comment: Downvote removed.

Comment: You can get first 10 rows of timestamp column by df.timestamp.head(10)

Comment: I believe OP wants the first 10 characters (the date part) from each row of the `timestamp` column. @zabop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your csv file, there are multiple methods to extract the date

**Method 1**: `parse_dates` from `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'])
df['date'] = df['timestamp'].dt.date
```

**Method 2**: `to_datetime`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.date
```

**Method 3**: `str[]`

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['date'] = df['timestamp'].str[:10]
```

The output of each method is:

```
>>> df['date']
1        2017-06-04
2        2017-06-04
3        2017-06-04
4        2017-06-04
            ...    
13065    2017-08-19
13066    2017-08-19
13067    2017-08-19
13068    2017-08-19
13069    2017-08-19
Name: date, Length: 13070, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 4:** str.split()

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') 
df['date'] = df['timestamp'].str.split().str[0]
```

split returns a list of the datetime string separated by spaces

```
df['timestamp'].str.split()
0    [2017-06-04, 07:59:42]
1    [2017-06-04, 07:59:42]
2    [2017-06-04, 07:59:42]
3    [2017-06-04, 07:59:42]
4    [2017-06-04, 07:59:42]
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```

and then you can get the first element of the list by

```
df['timestamp'].str.split().str[0]
0    2017-06-04
1    2017-06-04
2    2017-06-04
3    2017-06-04
4    2017-06-04
Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```